# How to solve jsdoc PluginConflictError in Grafana panel plugin?

Tags: grafana, grafana-plugin

I've made a Grafana panel plugin that has worked fine in the past, but now I'm getting this error when I run `yarn dev` (i.e. `grafana-toolkit plugin:dev`) to build the plugin:

> Plugin "jsdoc" was conflicted between "--config » @grafana/eslint-config" and "../../../.eslintrc » @grafana/eslint-config"

I'm using the following Grafana dependencies:

```
"@grafana/data": "^7.4.3",
"@grafana/runtime": "^7.4.3",
"@grafana/toolkit": "^7.4.3",
"@grafana/ui": "^7.4.3",
```

I've tried updating the dependencies to Grafana 8, clearing modules cache and re-installing modules but can't get rid of the error. I'm not sure what to do, since it looks like a conflict within the @grafana dependencies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the plugin out of my cloned grafana repo /plugins folder and editing the path for "plugins" in the default.ini file in grafana to point to the folder outside grafana. I've always just run the plugin inside grafana, but that no longer works for me. Maybe I missed that somewhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It appears to be a conflict with eslint config in a parent directory.  I fixed it by adding a .eslintrc in the plugin directory with the following contents.  The `root: true` flag indicates that this is the top level config.

```
{
    "extends": ["@grafana/eslint-config"],
    "root": true
}
```